# Get (super) simple jQuery array to start at 1 not 0

Tags: jquery, arrays

So

```
$(".section").attr("name", function (arr) {
      return "section" + arr;
})
```

obviously gives

```
<div class="section" name="section0"></div>
<div class="section" name="section1"></div>
<div class="section" name="section2"></div>
```

How can I make the sections start at 1?

Cheers!

Comment: `return "section" + (arr + 1);`

Comment: 356 rep and you really couldn't figure this out yourself?

Comment: Thought I tried that to be honest! Hmmm, lack of sleep... or caching. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".section").attr("name", function (arr) {
      return "section" + (arr+1);
})
```